# Rake gem not found issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am running ROR 3.0.1 with Ruby 1.9.2p0 on a Mac Mini with Snow Leopard 10.6.4.

when I run rake db:migrate I get the following error

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in`'

I have uninstalled and reinstalled rake but I still get the same error.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

When you're running the gem command, are you using "sudo"? Also, what do you get when you do "gem list rake"? And finally, what does "echo $PATH" give you? Check the return value of "which rake" while you're there in the terminal.

Comment: I do use sudo when I run the gem command.  When I do gem list rake I get local gems - rake (0.8.7). which rake returns /usr/local/bin/rake. echo $PATH returns - /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: Interesting. Ok, so those look Ok to me. One more command I'd like to know the output of. Run "gem which rake" for me and post the output.

Comment: gem which rake returns /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to remove this file:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/rake.gemspec
```

Apparently 1.9.2 comes with a version of rake internally, but has a problem finding it because of this gemspec file.